# loop through days of week beginning with today

Tags: php

I'm trying to loop through 6 days of week. I'd like to show the first item in the loop as today with a CSS class of 'active'. And if the day is Sunday, then for the loop to begin at 'Mon' with the 'active' class.

I've come up with the following, but not sure how to connect it all together correctly. Any clues?

```
$mydays = array('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat');

foreach ($mydays as $day) {
   if (date('D') === $day ) {
      echo '<li class="active">' . $day . '</li>';
   }
   if (date('D') === 'Sun') {
      echo '<li class="active">Mon</li>';
   }
   else {
      echo '<li>' . $day . '</li>';
   }
}
```

Comment: You want always today as the first item you show up?

Comment: Yes. that's right. So if it's Monday, Monday will be the first item in the list with an 'active' CSS class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class and the [`DateTime::add()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) method for that:

```
<?php

$datetime = new \DateTime();

$listItem = array('<li class="active">', '</li>');

$i = 0;
while (true) {
    if ($i === 6) break;
    
    if ($datetime->format('N') === '7' && $i === 0) {
        $datetime->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'));
        continue;        
    }
    
    echo $listItem[0] . $datetime->format('D') . $listItem[1];
    $listItem = array('<li>', '</li>');    
    
    $datetime->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'));
    $i++;
}
```

Basically it just start on today. If today is a Sunday it will be skipped. The first displayed day will automatically get the active class.

Demo: https://eval.in/69138

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$mydays = array('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat');
$outputvalues = array();
foreach ($mydays as $day) {
    if (date('D', $timestamp) === $day) {
        $outputvalues[] = '<li class="active">$day</li>';
    } else {
        $outputvalues[] = '<li>$day</li>';
    }
}
if (date('D', $timestamp) === 'Sun') {
    if (count($outputvalues) > 0) {
        $outputvalues[0] = '<li class="active">Mon</li>';
    }
}
foreach ($outputvalues as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$mydays = array('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat');
$start = date('w');

for($i = 0, $i++; $i < 6 {
   if(($start + $1) == 6){
       $start-=6;
   }
   if($i) {
      echo '<li>' . $mydays[$i] . '</li>';
   } else {
      echo '<li class="active">' . $mydays[$i] . '</li>';
   }
}
```

With this you will exactly 6 days, and always start with today.

Comment: Missing closing ) and incorrect usage of a for loop, please fix.