# Iterate over months/years; min and max values

Tags: php, loops, date

I have two dates in an array format {YYYY, MM}:

```
$min = {2014,7};
$max = {2015,4};
```

I'm trying to iterate through these, starting from the min values and working my way up to the max values. For example, I want to print the below:

```
7 in 2014
8 in 2014
9 in 2014
...
12 in 2014
1 in 2015
...
4 in 2015
```

Some code as below:

```
for ($i = $min["0"]; $i <= $max["0"]; $i++) { //year loop
    for ($j = max(1,$min["1"]); $j <= min(12,$max["1"]); $j++) { //month loop
        echo $j." in ".$i."</br>";
    }
    $min["1"] = 1;
}
```

I'm not too sure what to put in the nested for loop. This is as far as I've got, it doesn't quite work.

Comment: This should give you an idea http://stackoverflow.com/a/20032008/508666

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you want:

```
for ($i = $min["0"]; $i <= $max["0"]; $i++) {
    $end = ($i == $max["0"] ? $max["1"] : 12);
    for ($j = max(1,$min["1"]); $j <= $end; $j++) {
        echo $j." in ".$i."</br>";
    }
    $min["1"] = 1;
}
```

You just need to define what is the maximum number for each year, and that is 12 except for the last year.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind to consider an alternative, you could use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class as well:

```
$min = '{2014,7}';
$max = '{2015,4}';

$mn = DateTime::createFromFormat('{Y,n}', $min);
$mx = DateTime::createFromFormat('{Y,n}', $max);
$mx->modify('+1 month'); // add on ending
$i = new DateInterval('P1M'); // one month interval
$period = new DatePeriod($mn, $i, $mx);
foreach($period as $d) {
    echo "{$d->format('n')} in {$d->format('Y')} <br/>";
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://codepad.viper-7.com/pJrqMs)